# Gradle wrapper is causing "JAR files in classpath should have same version" errors

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Why am I getting conflicts? Does my Gradle project have to use the same version of the kotlin libraries as the Gradle Wrapper?

```
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/gradle-7.1.1/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/gradle-7.1.1/lib/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/gradle-7.1.1/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/gradle-7.1.1/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/gradle-7.1.1/lib/kotlin-reflect-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.21/6b3de2a43405a65502728047db37a98a0c7e72f0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.21.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.21/f059658740a4b3a3461aba9681457615332bae1c/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.21.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.21/2f537cad7e9eeb9da73738c8812e1e4cf9b62e4e/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.21.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.21/cc8bf3586fd2ebcf234058b9440bb406e62dfacb/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.21.jar (version 1.5)
```

In my `build.gradle.kt`

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.5.21"
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Comment: That's a Gradle bug - see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15020